# Generating unstructured finite volume mesh

Tags: finite-volume, mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh

I want to generate a triangular mesh over a rectangle domain in order to solve Euler equations. Most mesh generator generate a mesh while providing node connectivity for each element. This is convenient for finite element codes. Whereas finite volume codes for unstructured grids requires the center of each element, the faces (the tag of the two nodes that are separated by the face) and the face's normal.

Are there finite volume mesh generators?

Comment: What is the difference between a "triangular mesh" and a "finite element mesh"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad formulation, I will edit the question. Tell him if it more understandable.

Comment: Are you trying to use the two point flux approximation scheme so you need orthogonal meshes? You can use a Delaunay triangulation/Voronoi construction library.

Comment: *Yes, I am trying to use a two point flux approximation, but not necessarily on an orthogonal mesh.

Comment: @LMaxime Two point flux approximation schemes require the graphs to be orthogonal for consistency as far as I can remember, so I think you will have to use a Delaunay triangulation and its corresponding Voronoi mesh.

Comment: I still don't understand what specific property is required of the mesh. Please make sure that is in the question. "Finite volume mesh" is not specific enough.

Comment: It seems there is an edit pending making the question more specific. If this gets approved, I will delete my existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

“Finite volume” and “finite element” refer to ways of discretizing functions and operators over a mesh. The mesh generation itself is not strictly a part of either method and the same mesh can be used for both methods. However, different methods may perform better or worse on the same mesh.

Comment: I think my question should be: is there a library that postprocess an unstructured mesh in order to extract the needed objects so that the mesh is exploitable by a finite volume code?

Comment: Are you OP on another account?

Comment: Yes I am, I can receive the notifications on my other account.